# Context manager for SuspendLayout

Tags: c#

I've found a few places where control updates take longer than the redraw cycle.

I started off surrounding them with `Suspend` and `ResumeLayout`:

```
container.SuspendLayout(); 
updateControls(); 
container.ResumeLayout(true);
```

After doing that a few times, I realized it could be refactored into a context:

```
/// <summary>
/// Context manager to suspend and resume layout engine while performing 
/// updates that take longer than a refresh cycle
/// </summary>
/// <example>using (new SuspendLayoutContext(container)
///     DoSlowUpdate(container.Controls);</example>
class SuspendLayoutContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Control _control;
    private readonly bool _performLayoutAfter;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs the context manager to suspend and resume layout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container"></param>
    /// <param name="performLayout"></param>
    public SuspendLayoutContext(Control container, bool performLayoutAfter=true)
    {
        _control = container;
        _performLayoutAfter = performLayoutAfter;
        _control.SuspendLayout();
    }

    /// <summary>Calls ResumeLayout on the container.</summary>
    /// <remarks>If you call this manually, you are probably using this class wrong.</remarks>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _control.ResumeLayout(_performLayoutAfter);
    }
}
```

Then, the above code would look like

```
using (new SuspendLayoutContext(container))
{
    updateControls(); 
}
```

I then decided I didn't like having to call the constructor every time, so I created an extension method (`///` comments elided for brevity):

```
static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static SuspendLayoutContext SuspendLayoutContext(this Control container, bool performLayoutAfter=true)
    {
        return new SuspendLayoutContext(container, performLayoutAfter);
    }
}
```

The example then looks like

```
using (container.SuspendLayoutContext())
{
    updateControls(); 
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is there any reason *not* to use an `IDisposable` context here?  I'm more familiar with [python](/questions/tagged/python), where I wouldn't hesitate to create new context managers - but the method name `Dispose()` raises red flags. (In python, it's `__exit__`.)
2. I debated between the extension method on `Control` and a static method on `SuspendLayoutContext`:

   ```
   public static SuspendLayoutContext For(Control container, bool performLayoutAfter=true)
   {
       return new SuspendLayoutContext(container, performLayoutAfter)
   }
   ```

   While I'm a big fan of fluent interfaces, the extension method felt cleaner.  What alternatives might be better?
3. I always miss something when I do this, what is it this time?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is nothing wrong with using `IDisposable` whenever a class requires some sort of clean-up. It might have been originally designed to release unmanaged resources, but it is definitely no longer the case. Nowadays people use `IDisposable` to do all sort of things: unsubscribe from events, release pooled objects, flush buffers... this list goes on and on.

---

I also would prefer extension method over other options. It looks cleaner IMHO. What I don't like is the `Context` word. Not only because the method name should be a verb, but also because its somewhat misleading. I think a lot of people will assume that `...Context` class is the class that implements context object (anti-)pattern. But your class doesn't. For example, `class LayoutSuspender` both sounds funny and describes what the class does. Win-win.

---

The thing you should be careful about is using this class with nested methods. For example, this:

```
public void UpdateAllControls()
{
    using (container.SuspendLayoutContext())
    {
        UpdateControlA(); 
        UpdateControlB(); 
    }
} 

public void UpdateControlA()
{
    using (container.SuspendLayoutContext())
    {
        UpdateControlA(); 
    }
}
```

won't work as you want it to. So eventually you might want to implement some sort of reference counting.